# Template incompatible with last WP update

Tags: wordpress, themes

My page is no longer visible and I don't remember updating WP, it is possible that the last update is incompatible with my theme. Two questions have arisen:

1. Is it an automatic function of the web hosting service?
2. How can I fix this big problem?

> Warning: Declaration of description_walker::start_el(&$output, $item,
>   $depth, $args) should be compatible with
>   Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = Array,
>   $id = 0) in /usr/home/domino.com/web/eng/wp-content/themes/nebula/lib/functions/support_function.php ...

[Full warning message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/to4hu.jpg)

Comment: Please avoid post text as image. Read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: With that little information (WP version, theme version, PHP version missing) it's impossible to track down the problem. Apparently, the `nebula/lib/functions/custom_menudesc.php` (where this `mysql_query() undefined` error happens) no longer exists in the current version (7.7.10.7243) of this theme. You could try updating the theme and see if this fixes your problem. As this function was removed in PHP 7, it might also be that your hosting provider enforced a PHP update that broke the old theme - just a wild guess.